# How to get social media icons on a background image?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website for a school project. I currently have it up and working but need help with my social media icons to stay on the back ground image. I am using css to size them but I think I am missing something. If someone could please guide me towards the correct code. Thanks 
This my code for the social media button

```
.fa {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 30px;
width: 50px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 5px 2px;
}
.fa:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}
.fa-facebook {
background: #3B5998;
color: white;
}
 .fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
  }
 .fa-snapchat-ghost {
  background: #fffc00;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  }
  .fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
  }
```

when I scroll to the end of the page the its white with the social media icons displaying.

Sorry left the html off here is the html

```
     </form>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div style="padding-bottom:16px">
     <div Class="module mid">
     <h2>Welcome to Uniforms Today.</h2>
     <div class="module h1">
     <h1>The website that helps parents and kids get their school 
     uniforms.</h1>
     </div>
     </div>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com
     /ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: We can't help you much without a better context. There is no HTML code and you have the HTML tag in your question. Please make sure to provide the necessary code for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 background attribute on 1 class but as I researched it is a little tricky.

Instead of using 1 colour attribute, you need to use a gradient colour attribute like this following code:

```
.fa-facebook {
    background-image: url('[facebook-icon-link]'), linear-gradient(to right, #3B5998, #3B5998);
    background-position: center, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size:contain,contain;
}
```

You can follow the guideline from this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds